# React Guarantee that part of function runs after DOM updates

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Currently I have a textarea like this:

```js
<textarea
    onChange={handleTextAreaChange}
    ref={textAreaRef as MutableRefObject<HTMLTextAreaElement>}
    id={id}
    value={content}
></textarea>
```

I am implementing some buttons to add markdown to the textarea to make it easier for the user to update and have this function for bold:

```js
const handleBoldClick = useCallback(() => {
    const selectionStart = textAreaRef.current?.selectionStart;
    const selectionEnd = textAreaRef.current?.selectionEnd;

    if (selectionStart && selectionEnd) {
        setContent(
            prevContent =>
                prevContent.substring(0, selectionStart) +
                '**' +
                prevContent.substring(selectionStart, selectionEnd) +
                '**' +
                prevContent.substring(selectionEnd, prevContent.length)
        );
    } else {
        setContent(prevContent => prevContent + '****');

        // Want this to run after textarea gets updated
        textAreaRef.current?.focus();
        textAreaRef.current?.setSelectionRange(
            content.length - 3,
            content.length - 3
        );
    }

    const changeEvent = new Event('change', { bubbles: true });

    // Want to run this after textarea is updated
    textAreaRef.current?.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
}, [content]);
```

`setContent` is the setter for `content` which is passed to the textarea. Is there a way to guarantee the parts I've marked with comments as wanting to only run once the DOM gets updated run when I want them to?

Comment: Use `window.requestAnimationFrame` and dispatch the event in the callback?

Comment: I could maybe see that working. I'm currently experimenting with adding a changed state that gets set in the bold function and gets caught and unset in an if block in the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finagled around with things and went with this approach (gonna post the entire component, which contains some stuff irrelevant to the question):

```js
const MarkdownTextArea = ({
    value,
    onBlur = () => {},
    onChange = () => {},
    touched = false,
    error,
    id,
    label
}: MarkdownTextAreaProps) => {
    const [content, setContent] = useState(value ?? '');
    const [numberOfRows, setNumberOfRows] = useState(5);
    const [numberOfCols, setNumberOfCols] = useState(20);
    const [isPreview, setIsPreview] = useState(false);
    const [changed, setChanged] = useState<'bold' | null>();

    const textAreaRef = useRef<HTMLTextAreaElement>();

    useEffect(() => {
        const setColsAndRows = () => {
            const newColumnsNumber = Math.floor(
                (textAreaRef.current?.offsetWidth ?? 100) /
                    (convertRemToPixels(1.2) / 1.85)
            );
            setNumberOfCols(newColumnsNumber);
            setNumberOfRows(calculateNumberOfRows(content, newColumnsNumber));
        };

        setColsAndRows();

        window.addEventListener('resize', setColsAndRows);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('resize', setColsAndRows);
        };
    }, [content]);

    const handleTextAreaChange: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLTextAreaElement> =
        useCallback(
            event => {
                onChange(event);
                setContent(event.target.value);

                setNumberOfRows(
                    calculateNumberOfRows(
                        event.target.value,
                        textAreaRef.current?.cols ?? 20
                    )
                );
            },
            [onChange]
        );

    const handleBoldClick = useCallback(() => {
        const selectionStart = textAreaRef.current?.selectionStart;
        const selectionEnd = textAreaRef.current?.selectionEnd;

        if (selectionStart && selectionEnd) {
            setContent(
                prevContent =>
                    prevContent.substring(0, selectionStart) +
                    '**' +
                    prevContent.substring(selectionStart, selectionEnd) +
                    '**' +
                    prevContent.substring(selectionEnd, prevContent.length)
            );
        } else {
            setContent(prevContent => prevContent + '****');
        }

        setChanged('bold');
    }, []);

    if (changed && textAreaRef.current?.value === content) {
        const changeEvent = new Event('change', { bubbles: true });

        textAreaRef.current?.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);

        if (changed === 'bold' && textAreaRef.current) {
            textAreaRef.current.focus();
            textAreaRef.current.selectionStart = content.length - 2;
            textAreaRef.current.selectionEnd = content.length - 2;
        }

        setChanged(null);
    }

    return (
        <div className={classes.container} data-testid="markdown-text-area">
            <div className={classes['header']}>
                <label className={classes.label} htmlFor={id}>
                    {label}
                </label>
                <Button
                    positive
                    style={{ justifySelf: 'flex-end' }}
                    onClick={() => setIsPreview(prev => !prev)}
                >
                    {isPreview ? 'Edit' : 'Preview'}
                </Button>
            </div>
            <div className={classes['text-effect-buttons']}>
                <button
                    className={classes['text-effect-button']}
                    onClick={handleBoldClick}
                    type="button"
                    style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}
                >
                    B
                </button>
            </div>
            {isPreview ? (
                <div className={classes['markdown-container']} id={id}>
                    <MarkdownParser input={content} />
                </div>
            ) : (
                <textarea
                    onChange={handleTextAreaChange}
                    className={`${classes['text-input']}${
                        error && touched ? ` ${classes.error}` : ''
                    }`}
                    ref={textAreaRef as MutableRefObject<HTMLTextAreaElement>}
                    rows={numberOfRows}
                    cols={numberOfCols}
                    onBlur={onBlur}
                    id={id}
                    value={content}
                ></textarea>
            )}
            {error && touched && (
                <div className={classes['error-message']}>{error}</div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};
```

The part of the following component most relevant to answering the question is the following:

```js
 if (changed && textAreaRef.current?.value === content) {
        const changeEvent = new Event('change', { bubbles: true });

        textAreaRef.current?.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);

        if (changed === 'bold' && textAreaRef.current) {
            textAreaRef.current.focus();
            textAreaRef.current.selectionStart = content.length - 2;
            textAreaRef.current.selectionEnd = content.length - 2;
        }

        setChanged(null);
  }
```